# How to make dropdown list populated in loop in Angular 6 HTML?

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of employees to which tests are assigned by Lead. When assigning tests, selected employee is assigned properly. while populating back, Lead can see which test is assigned to which employee.

I am facing issue is, EmployeeID is populated correct but its corresponding employee name is different.

Employee id and names are like <1, FName1>, <2, FName2>, <3, FName3>, <4, FName4>

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm m-0 w-auto">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let t of tests">
                <td>
                    {{t.empid}} //Correct EmployeeID populated
                    <select *ngIf="t" id="assigned" name="assignedName" [(ngModel)]="t.empid" class="form-control">
                        <option *ngFor="let e of empids; let i = index" [value]="empids[i].employeeid">
                            {{empids[i].employeename}}   //Wrong employee Name populated
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Screenshot of result is as below where employeeID is populating correctly but EmployeeName is wrong.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot after updating code to e.employeename

[image]

Comment: empids details as follows

(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
employeeid: 3
employeename: "FName3"
middlename: null
password: "Three"
role: "Analyst"
surname: "LName3"
username: "Three"
__proto__: Object
1: {employeeid: 4, employeename: "FName4", middlename: null, surname: "LName4", username: "Four", …}
2: {employeeid: 143, employeename: "Kiran", middlename: "K", surname: "Kiran", username: "kiranA", …}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `e.employeename` like you did for the value `e.employeeid`

```
<select *ngIf="t" id="assigned" name="assignedName" [(ngModel)]="t.empid" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let e of empids; let i = index" [value]="e.employeeid">
         {{e.employeename}} // Change your code here
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tried this but still same result, not working.
While populating back, value is in '[(ngModel)]="t.empid"'. I need to populate same value from 'empids' array. Do we need to do any comparison of t.empid to Array?

Comment: What does the array `empids` value holds? If you can share the data

Comment: empids details as follows

(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
employeeid: 3
employeename: "FName3"
middlename: null
password: "Three"
role: "Analyst"
surname: "LName3"
username: "Three"
__proto__: Object
1: {employeeid: 4, employeename: "FName4", middlename: null, surname: "LName4", username: "Four", …}
2: {employeeid: 143, employeename: "Kiran", middlename: "K", surname: "Kiran", username: "kiranA", …}

Comment: Logically this should've worked. What's the result when you tried to use `e.employeename`?

Comment: Its same result as in question. Added screenshot in question.

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache or run `ng serve` again and see if the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to reference the index in this case.

Your current HTML

```
<option *ngFor="let e of empids; let i = index" [value]="empids[i].employeeid">
    {{empids[i].employeename}}   //Wrong employee Name populated
</option>
```

Can be updated to

```
<option *ngFor="let e of empids; let i as index" [value]="e.employeeid">
    {{e.employeename}} 
</option>
```

Comment: Tried this but still same result, not working.
While populating back, value is in '[(ngModel)]="t.empid"'. I need to populate same value from 'empids' array. Do we need to do any comparison of t.empid to Array?